# Question on Inequality from Bartle's Elements of Integration: Riesz Fischer Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I am puzzled how did Bartle get $$|g_k|\leq\sum_{j=k}^\infty |g_{j+1}-g_j|$$ (second last line)?

I tried using Triangle Inequality and ended up with one extra term:

$$\begin{align*}
|g_k|&=|g_k-g_{k+1}+g_{k+1}-g_{k+2}\dots+g_{k+N-1}-g_{k+N}+g_{k+N}|\\
&\leq\sum_{j=k}^{N-1}|g_{j+1}-g_j|+|g_{k+N}|
\end{align*}$$

Even after taking limits $N\to\infty$, the extra term $|g_{k+N}|$ does not necessarily go to zero.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: FYI essentially the latest edition of Bartle has the correct version of the point you were asking about, which in the first edition is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the inequality you mention, but since $|g_k| \le g$ seems to be sufficient for your purposes, you can get this by
\begin{align*}
|g_k|
&= |g_1+(g_2-g_1)+\dots+(g_k-g_{k-1})| \\
&\le |g_1|+|g_2-g_1|+\dots|+|g_k-g_{k-1}|\\
&=|g_1| + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} |g_{j+1}-g_j| \\
&\le |g_1| + \sum_{j=1}^\infty |g_{j+1}-g_j|=g
\end{align*}
I.e., you can use the same sum as in your book, but the range is not $j\ge k$, but $j<k$.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this inequality is sufficient for my purposes.